# How to get the array modifier to snap to vertices?

Tags: modifiers, snapping

### Overview

I've created 9 tiles I can snap together to form a surface with a hexagonal pattern. I can manually snap them together, but this is quite tedious. The Array modifier seems promising, but I'm not sure how to (easily) make it exact.

[image: Image with the tiles, a previously-built wall on the side, and indicators where vertices should snap to each other.]

Conceptually, it's simple. We just tile center pieces so white snaps to white horizontally, and grey to grey vertically. For each side, we snap an edge green to green on the left and bottom, and yellow to yellow right and top. Then red, orange, purple and blue for the corners. In practice though, I don't see any way to attach snapping points for this to work neatly.

My hope is someone has a better way than what I'm doing.

### Current Method

A method that basically works should be a two-phase process. First, create horizontal strips for the top edge, center area, and bottom edge using array modifiers on the top, center, and bottom pieces using the upper corners, side edges, and lower corners as cap pieces.

Next, grow the wall vertically using an array modifier on the previously-generated center strip using the top and bottom strips as cap pieces.

The problem is it doesn't work as expected for the shapes I'm using.

1. I have to calculate the relative offset. Horizontally is pretty easy because I need to move 4 hexes, and each tile is 4.5 hexes wide. Just plug 8/9 into the offset field and we're good. But it's less obvious the vertical offset needs to be 12/13*, and I'd prefer a generic solution that doesn't require knowing how to calculate things.

   - It's 4 caps + 4 midsections out of 5 caps + 4 midsections, but knowing each cap is half the height of a midsection, and that the height is therefore 6 mids out of 6.5 mids and applying a 12/13 offset, requires more critical thinking than I want to do on a regular basis.
2. The end caps are completely wrong and don't line up at all. The vertical location is too high, even though it should be right just by doing geometric center calculations, both appear to use a relative horizontal offset of 1, and the right cap is rotated 180° from where it should be. I don't see any place to adjust the offset or rotation for the caps, so I have to manually place them after applying the array modifier to the center pieces.

[image: Image with incorrect end caps and arrows showing how they should be moved.]

3. Using the array modifier vertically works fine for the center strip (other than requiring me to calculate the offset), but similarly breaks when using the top and bottom strips as caps.
4. Also, I'd still like a way to build a 2D grid in one step instead of two.

### Conclusion

Using vertex snapping, it's not too hard to create horizontal strips using three arrays, manually add end caps, use a fourth array to tile the center strip vertically, then manually merge the top and bottom to accomplish what I want.

But I feel like I can't be the only person trying to accomplish this, and am hoping there's a way to set this up to create arbitrarily-sized walls for the various scenes I'm planning to build with this style with minimal fuss.

Comment: did you ever take a look at geometry nodes? this is a pretty easy task there. Yes, it takes some time to learn it...but i can strongly recommend it. It's awesome.